# Reverting Values Inside a Tensorflow Placeholder

Tags: tensorflow

I have a **placeholder** which contains zeros and ones (Type Int32). How can I reverse all the ones to zer and all the zeros to one in that placeholder?

```
A=[[0,1,1],
 [1,0,0]] 
 type=int32

C=[[1,0,0],
 [0,1,1]]
 type=int32
```

Comment: I don't think the `deep-learning` tag belongs here, to say the least...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your example as a basis for the (very very very simple) solution:

```
# numpy version:
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[0,1,1],
             [1,0,0]], dtype=np.uint32)     
C = 1 - A
print(C)
>> [[1 0 0]
   [0 1 1]]

# tensorflow version:
import tensorflow as tf
A = tf.constant([[0,1,1],
                [1,0,0]], dtype=tf.int32)
C = 1 - A
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(C))
>> [[1 0 0]
   [0 1 1]]
```

Hope that helps.